# Linear indexing of 3D matrix: best way to expand the first 2 dims to a vector (slow sprintf on scalars)

Tags: matlab, printf

I have a 3D vector `s1`(nmax,mmax,ntimeSTEPS). I want to take at each time step `j` (i.e. each value of the third dimension) all the elements of the first two dimensions and obtain a vector to give to `sprintf`. However, `sprintf` is PAINFULLY SLOW if inside a cycle! I checked the manual and it looks like there is no way to do that directly with linear indexing. Or am I missing something? I can only think of using `reshape`, but something like `s1(:,j)` would be the top, but that's not how MATLAB works. I did:

```
        nmax = 800;
        mmax =400;
        nmax_x_mmax = nmax*mmax;
        ntimeSTEPS = 1;
        charINPUT = cell(nmax_x_mmax,1);
        s1 = ones(nmax,mmax,ntimeSTEPS)*1234;
        tic
        for j=1:ntimeSTEPS
            %... other stuff
            input=reshape(s1(:,:,j),nmax_x_mmax,1);
            for kk=1:length(input)
                charINPUT{kk} = sprintf('%6.3f',input(kk));
            end
            %... other stuff  (collecting movie frames etc)
        end
        toc
```

This on a single time steps takes 5.09 SECONDS on my i7 2.2 GHz! I am trying to do an animation and this is crazily slow. If I increase the size of the array its basically stuck.
Any suggestion for doing this with linear indexes?

Comment: You can use `sprintf` and `regexp` to get the cell you need in one line.  See my answer.

Comment: Keep in mind you can read a 2D (or 3D) array with a single index without reshaping it.  (You can get rid of your `reshape` command and get the same result, AND you can use a single loop as Alexandre suggested.)  I have a loop-free solution just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `sprintf`

`sprintf` can take an array.  Output with newlines and use `regexp` to parse out the digits and put them in a cell array of strings.

```
charINPUT = regexp(sprintf('%6.3f\n',s1(:)),'(?<=\s*)(\S*)(?=\n)','match')
```

### Without `sprintf`

You don't have to use `sprintf` in a loop to build your cell array of strings.  Since `num2str` takes a format specifier, you can just do this for the whole thing:

```
charINPUT = cellstr(num2str(s1(:),'%6.3f'))
```

You can either skip the loop over `ntimeSTEPS` entirely, or if you are performing other operations you are not showing that require the loop you can handle indexing as follows.

For direct indexing of `s1` with no temporary variable, you can compute the linear indexes yourself via `(1:nmax*nmax) + (j-1)*nmax*nmax`.

```
for j=1:ntimeSTEPS,
    stepInds = (1:nmax*nmax) + (j-1)*nmax*nmax;
    charINPUT = cellstr(num2str(s1(stepInds),'%6.3f'))
end
```

Comment: I am not sure that the first option would work. I opened the function num2str, it is calling convertUsingRecycledSprintf that does a cycle on the column indexes...so you dont avoid the cycle plus the overloading of the call

Comment: I thought about the second option, but it involves extra sums and multiplications...here still overload. I am trying to optimize at best since it takes half a minute every time (huge matrix)

Comment: Well, you can run `sprintf` with an array too:   `sprintf('%6.3f\n',s1(:));`

Comment: The point is that, sorry maybe I did not specified, I edited the post, but when you speak of time loop you usually do some time varying plots and stuff so clearly each time I plot those texts labels on a 2D plot. so I need only the first two dimensions each time step.

Comment: Ok you are great regexp made the trick! its 6.1 times faster with that! can I edit your post and copy and paste your solution applied to mine withe the timing? In this way its the best answer. Still no linear indexing without storing extra variable, I would write that on your answer, there is no way to do it I guess.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to have helped.  Sure go ahead and add the timings.
But I'm still confused by what you mean with linear indexing w/o storing extra variable.  Doesn't the loop in my last solution do the indexing the way you mean?  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Nope it does not work. You cannot select the first two dimensions sonly, but only all the array.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `x = reshape(1:8,[2 2 2]); x(4+2)` gives you `x(1,1,2)`.

Comment: Check my edit. There is no way to do linear indexing without computing the linear indexes yourself. And that slows things down a bit. Unless u have a better option. But the hint of using regexp is simply awesome thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for idx = 1:numel(s1)
    charINPUT{idx} = sprintf('%6.3f',s1(idx));    
end
```

Comment: It will.  Your nested loops do the same thing.  You don't even need the reshape.

Comment: Nope it does not work, you need 2 nested do cycles. I tried, unless  I am missing something